# Are there some projects that rate RPG source? like software metrics?

Tags: code-analysis, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I just wanted to know if you know of some projects that can *help* to decide whether the analyzed Source it is good code or bad RPG code.

I'm thinking on the terms of [Software metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_metric), [McCabe Cyclomatic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) and all those things.

I know that those numbers are mere a hunch or two, but if you can present your management a point score they are happy and i get to modernize all those programs that otherwise *work as specified* but are painful to maintain.

so yeah .. know any code analyzers for (ILE)RPG ?

Comment: Note that this technically seems to be off-topic due to asking to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_.

Answer (score 4):

We have developed a tool called [SourceMeter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/) that can analyze source code conforming to RPG III and RPG IV versions (including free-form as well). It provides you the McCabe Cyclomatic Number and many other source code metrics that you can use to rate your RPG code.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that the programs are painful to maintain, then the metric should reflect how how much pain is involved with maintaining them, such as "time to implement new feature X" vs "estimated time if codebase wasn't a steaming POS".

However, those are subjective (and always will be).  IMO you're probably better off [refactoring mercilessly](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/refactor.html) to remove pain points from your development.  You may want to look at the techniques of [strangler applications](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerApplication.html) to bring in a more modern platform to deliver new features without resorting to a Big Bang rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

The [SD Source Code Search Engine (SCSE)](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) is a tool for rapidly search very large set of source code, using the langauge structure of each file to index the file according to code elements (identifiers, operators, constants, string literals, comments).  The SD Source code engine is usable with a wide variety of langauges such as C, C++, C#, Java ... and there's a draft version of RPG.

To the OP's original question, the  SCSE engine happens to compute various metrics over files as it indexes them, including SLOC, Comments, blank lines, and Halstead and Cyclomatic Complexity measures.  The metrics are made available as byprooduct of the indexing step.   Thus, various metrics for RPG could be obtained.

Comment: As of today (6 years later) there is still no RPG support. RPG is still only listed on the "tools in development" page.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint.  Sometimes things don't work out as expected :-{  The demand isn't very high (note that Front End Arts *just* added one 6 years after this answer!) We still have draft RPG support; it handles a generic version of RPG, but not any specific dialect completely.  We have actually used it on a custom project,  but won't mark it as available  until we do handle a specific dialect completely.  You can probably tell we've been busy with lots of other languages and tools.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen one, although I wrote a primitive analyser for RPG400.  With the advent of free form and subprocedures, it was too time consuming to modify.  I wish there was an API that let me have access to the compiler lexical tables.

If you wanted to try it yourself, consider the notion of reading the bottom of the compiler listing and using the line numbers to at least get an idea of how long a variable lives.  For instance, a global variable is 'worse' than a local variable.  That can only be a guess because of GOTO and EXSR.

Lot of work.